# How to call function Clean cache in magento2?

Tags: magento2, cache

I have custom module add  data to core_config_data.i want after save can auto clean cache. Any help? thks.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit late, but this answer is intended for those who will arrive here from Google, as myself.

To clean the cache after saving new value, you need to inject Cache Manager in the constructor, and then call 'flush' method in it with cache tag 'config' passed as a parameter.

Example:

`use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager as CacheManager;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config as CacheTypeConfig;
 .
 .
 $this->_cacheManager->clean([CacheTypeConfig::CACHE_TAG])`

I couldn't manage to have it re-populated on the same request, but the next one is getting it right (meaning the updated value).

Answer (score 1):

Try with this..

```
$command = 'php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush';
echo '<pre>' . shell_exec($command) . '</pre>';
```

Please be sure you can actually excecute php from the command line, else this will be useless. For windows you have to make sure you have added the php.exe to your PATH in the Environment Variables. Please see http://willj.co/2012/10/run-wamp-php-windows-7-command-line/

Comment: This would be bad practice since it sounds like this would be added into a custom module. Avoid shell commands and use the Magento API

Answer (score 1):

use function `clean($arrayCateTags)` in `\Magento\Framework\App\Cache`